# Print HTML Response with localhost cUrl - Linux

Tags: linux, curl

I want to execute PHP Script on my Ubuntu Virtual Machine but I only have access to the command line. I've thought about using cUrl but I have a problem with it :

When I use the following command : "curl http://localhost/myscript.php"

The response is the plain file ("`<?php echo "<p>Hello world</p>"; ?>`") instead of html response ("`<p>Hello world</p>`")

How to solve this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the content-type using header().

Before the echo statement, insert this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: It doesn't work : It response "<?php header('Content-Type: text/html'); echo "<p>Hello World"</p>"?> " It's like if the php is not executed if I run it from localhost.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Do you have php enabled on it?